# Enumeration of mixed values (constants and data class)

Tags: kotlin, enums

I have the following `data class` representing a color from red/green/blue values :

```kotlin
data class HexColor(
  val red:   Byte,
  val blue:  Byte,
  val green: Byte
)
```

I'm trying to create an enumeration with defined colors (`RED`, `YELLOW`, `PURPLE`, ...) **and** colors from other red/green/blue possibilities (using `HexColor`) :

```kotlin
enum class Color {
  RED,
  YELLOW,
  PURPLE,
  // ...
  HEX_COLOR: HexColor // how to represent this ?
}
```

The previous code does not compile, but just shows the general idea I want to implement.

How can I define my `enum` to represent a `Color` as defined values without parameters (constants like `YELLOW` for example) and `HexColor` (a data class with parameters). Is it possible ?

The idea is to use like this, or something similar :

```kotlin
val red = Color.RED
val blue = Color.HEX_COLOR(0, 255, 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's rather not possible with an enum class (all enum instances need to be defined at the compile time), but you can try something like this:

```kotlin
class Color private constructor(val r: Float, val g: Float, val b: Float) {
    companion object {
        val RED = Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
        val GREEN = Color(0.0f,1.0f, 0.0f)
        val BLUE = Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
        fun HEX_COLOR(r: Float, g: Float, b: Float) = Color(r, g, b)
    }
}
```